# Generic Observer Pattern in Swift using Protocols gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault

```
import Foundation
class IProtocol {
     func meth1(arg: Int){}
}
class IObserver: IProtocol {
    private var className: String
    init(name: String) {
        className = name
    }
    override func meth1(arg: Int) {
        print(className, ":", arg)
    }
}
class Notifier<T> {
    private var listOfObservers = NSMutableArray()
    func addObserver(observer: T) {
        listOfObservers.add(observer)
    }
    func callObservers<ARG, RET>(function: (T)->(ARG)->RET, arg: ARG) {
        for obj in listOfObservers {
            let observer = obj as! T
            _ = function(observer)(arg)
        }
    }
}
let a = IObserver(name: "First I Observer")
let b = IObserver(name: "Second I Observer")
let n = Notifier<IProtocol>()
n.addObserver(observer: a)
n.addObserver(observer: b)
n.callObservers(function: IProtocol.meth1, arg: Int(1))
```

**OUTPUT** 
First I Observer: 1
Second I Observer: 1
The above example fails and does not build giving **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault: 11**, when I change **IProtocol** to **protocol** from **class**. I have different protocols and different observer classes confirming those protocols. I am trying to implement a Notifier class that notifies the observers by taking the method from the protocol and arguments to be passed for that method.
It will be great, if someone can explain what am I doing wrong!
I am using **Swift 3** and **Xcode 8.2**

Comment: The compiler should never crash. You should file a bug at https://bugs.swift.org. I assume you're removing the `{}` from `meth1(arg:)` when you change it to a protocol?

Comment: Yes Dave, I remove the {} and also the override keyword from IObserver class.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, **Swift does not handle direct references to protocol methods**:

```
protocol IProtocol {
    func meth1()
}
class IObserver: IProtocol {
    func meth1() { print("success") }
}
let x = IProtocol.meth1 // This causes the compiler crash
x(IObserver())()
```

And coming to the solution for my problem was to pass a closure instead of the method. This is how it looks:

```
import Foundation
protocol IProtocol {
    func meth1(arg: Int)
}
class IObserver: IProtocol {
    private var className: String
    init(name: String) {
        className = name
    }
    func meth1(arg: Int) {
        print(className, ":", arg)
    }
}
class Notifier<T> {
    private var listOfObservers = NSMutableArray()
    func addObserver(observer: T) {
        listOfObservers.add(observer)
    }
    func callObservers<ARG>(function: (T, ARG) -> (), arg: ARG) {
        for obj in listOfObservers {
            let observer = obj as! T
            function(observer, arg)
        }
    }
}
let a = IObserver(name: "First I Observer")
let b = IObserver(name: "Second I Observer")
let n = Notifier<IProtocol>()
n.addObserver(observer: a)
n.addObserver(observer: b)
n.callObservers(function: {obs, ar in
    obs.meth1(arg: ar)
}, arg: Int(1))
```